# Show Continuous Random Variable with Conditional Probability Given CDF

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

I'm having trouble composing the proof for a random variable with conditional probability. Would like some help on proof construction.
I'm still pretty new to the forum, the post format maybe a bit messy.

> **Problem:**
>
> Suppose $Y$ is a continuous random variable with distribution function $F(y)$, and density $f(y)$. Show that the conditional probability that $Y\lt y$, given that $Y$ exceeds a constant, $c$ is
>
> $$ \mathbb{P}(Y\lt y | Y\ge c) = \frac {F(y)-F(c)}{1-F(c)}, $$
> $$1-F(c)\neq0 $$

Proof Attempt:

$$\mathbb{P}(c \le Y \lt y )= P(Y \lt y)-P(Y \le c)=F(y)-F(c)$$

And

$$\mathbb{P}(Y \ge c )= 1- P(Y\lt c)= 1-F(c)$$

Therefore

$$\mathbb{P}(Y\lt y | Y\ge c) = \frac {F(y)-F(c)}{1-F(c)}$$

Recall that in general $\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.
I do understand that $\Pr(B) = 1- P(Y\lt c) = 1-F(c)$, but is having trouble prove $F(y) - F(c) = \Pr(A\cap B)$ .It is not hard to see the overlap/intersection by drawing a number line, but how should I construct a proof that validates the relationship?

Comment: What if $1 - F(c) = 0$ as would be the case if $c > 0$ and $Y \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0, c/2)?$

Comment: @ BruceET I think this should be excluded.

Comment: Yes, the problem needs some specifications for possible values of $y$ and $c$.

Comment: @BruceET I wished for that as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: We know that the event A and B is $c \leq Y < y$. How can you write this using only the CDF?

Comment: by writing it as $1-F(c)<F(y)$?

Comment: Not quite - take a uniform distribution on [0,1]  as an example. What is the probability something is between 1/4 and 3/4?

Comment: 1/(3/4-1/4) = 2 . Therefore, can I write $1/(F(y)-F(c))$ as in uniform distribution?

Comment: Almost! Remember that probability must be between 0 and 1. So, P(we fall between 1/4 and 3/4) = P( less than 3/4) - P(less than 1/4) = 3/4 - 1/4 = 1/2. Now see if you can generalize this.

Comment: $P(c < Y < y) = P(Y<y) - P(Y<c)$?

Comment: Yes! And now use the definition of the CDF to note that F(c) = P(Y < c) and F(y) = P(Y < y), and you are done.

Comment: I have edited the main post with the attempted proof, hopefully I'm on the right track..

Comment: That looks good. You may want to say $P( Y < y | Y \geq c) = \frac{P(Y<y\text{ and } Y \geq c)}{P( Y \geq c)}$, and then write out why $P(Y<y\text{ and } Y \geq c)$ intuitively. But, this all looks good.